# Unable to connect to any of the torrent indexers

Tags: wifi, ethernet, connection, internet

I have freshly setup DietPi on my Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB). I had the same DietPi set up earlier for months and it worked fine but after this fresh installation, I am unable to connect to any of the torrent indexers through `jackett` or `curl`.

For example:

```
curl -v https://1337x.to
```

gives me :

```
*   Trying 104.31.16.11:443...
* Connected to 1337x.to (104.31.16.11) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to 1337x.to:443
* Closing connection 0
```

The same command with https://google.com works fine

```
*   Trying 142.251.12.139:443...
* Connected to google.com (142.251.12.139) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
.
.
.
```

I am not sure what could be causing this. Is this an ISP problem? The RPi is connected over Wi-Fi to my router. The router is configured to run on Cloudfare's `1.1.1.1` DNS and the DietPi is configured to use `9.9.9.9`. On my personal laptop's browser, opening `1337x.to` fails but it eventually loads up.

What should I try to fix this?